# Java :: comparing ronded doubles doesn't work

Tags: java, boolean, compare, double, decimal

I want to compare two numbers:

- `-3.123`
- `-3.123456`

I will use `double` to store them and I just want to consider **the first 3 decimals**, so:

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class DecimalComparator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(-3.123, -3.123456);
    }

    public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces (double one, double two) {
        boolean same = true;

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        System.out.println(df.format(one));
        System.out.println(df.format(two));

        if (df.format(one).equals(df.format(two))) {
            same = true;
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            same = false;
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        return same;
    }
}
```

The code is returning me:

```
-3.123
-3.124
false
```

why the second number is rounding to -3.124?

Comment: Ni @Mureinik, I checked '.equals()' but I have the same result

Comment: Using `==` is definitely wrong here, but I see you've corrected your post to use `equals`, so I've reopened it. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61137162/2422776) below for the current problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hi its just that when u round off 3.123456 it works the below way when decimal 
places are reduced :

 3.12346
 3.1235
 3.124
 3.12
 3.1 

//commenting the set rounding mode will make it work the way u want.
public static void main (String[] args ) {
        double one =-3.123;
         double two = -3.123456;
        boolean same = true;

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        //remove this line
        //df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);

        System.out.println(df.format(one));
        System.out.println(df.format(two));

        if (df.format(one).equals(df.format(two))) {
            same = true;
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            same = false;
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        System.out.println(same);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`RoundingMode.FLOOR` rounds the number towards the lower side - your code would work for positive numbers, but not for negative numbers. You need to use [`RoundingMode.DOWN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN) that just removes digits after N places:

```java
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
// Here ------------------------^
```

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik, but how to make it work for both positive and negative numbers?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani If it was unclear, I meant that using `FLOOR`, like you did in the question, would only work for positive numbers. Using `RoundingMode.DOWN`, as I did in my answer, will work for both positives and negatives.